# two words as one lemma in python

Tags: python, nlp

I want to produce a word cloud based on my text. I am using the following code:

```
import wordcloud
cloud = WordCloud(background_color='white').generate(str(mytext))

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), facecolor=None)
plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

the problem is that my text has economic or other terms which should be really thought as one word/expression. For example:

```
mytext = "financial crisis and climate change are two issues relevant for monetary policy"
```

I want the code to understand that `financial crisis`, `climate change` and `monetary policy` to be understood as one word/expression and counted accordingly.

I think the most general solution should ask the user to specify which terms need to be grouped.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: How do you want the code to be able to understand it?  E.g. do you want to tell it about specific terms that should be grouped, or do you want it to have a good enough understanding of the English language/vocabulary as a whole to be able to identify noun phrases in a sentence?

Comment: yes, maybe more flexible/general to tell about specific terms that should be grouped. Good question. I will update my post.

Comment: Looking at the doc (https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud) -- have you tried playing with the `collocations` parameter?

Comment: The other option would be to use `generate_from_words_and_frequencies`, which allows you to specify the input words.  If you have specific phrases you want to clump, rather than letting `wordcloud` figure it out, that seems like the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you want is to do your own tokenization, e.g.:

```
import string
from typing import List


def clump(text: str, phrases: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    for p in phrases:
        text = text.replace(p, p.replace(" ", "-"))
    return [word.replace("-", " ") for word in text.split()]
```

```
>>> clump(mytext, ["financial crisis", "climate change", "monetary policy"])
['financial crisis', 'and', 'climate change', 'are', 'two', 'issues', 'relevant', 'for', 'monetary policy']
```

Build a `collections.Counter` out of the token list and pass that to `WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies`:

```
from collections import Counter

...

mytext = "financial crisis and climate change are two issues relevant for monetary policy"
phrases = ["financial crisis", "climate change", "monetary policy"]

cloud = WordCloud(background_color='white').generate_from_frequencies(
    Counter(clump(mytext, phrases))
)
```